# Passing a string from AsyncTask to onCreate or other Activities

Tags: android

I am trying to query JSON data on a background thread using AsyncTask and use one of the values from the query in onCreate of the same Activity.  How should I do this? Should I use intents or is there a more intuitive and better way of doing it?

In my code below, I am trying to pull the youtube ID using an AsyncTask out of an online database.  It works because when I log the value inside the AsyncTask, the correct youtube ID is shown.  But I need to use this ID in onCreate so that I can use it to create the full youtube URL.  How can I pass the youtube ID string from doInBackground to onCreate?  The id is stored in the variable youtubeId

```
 //Activity needs added to manifest.
public class DetailsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    //LOG tag for debugging
    private static final String TAG = "GalleryActivity";

    String youtubeIdCode;

    //Override on Create and set contentView to new activity_details layout.
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_details);
        //Log for debugging so we can tell if activity started successfully.
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: started.");

        loadMovieData();

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Movie movie = intent.getParcelableExtra("movie");

        String image = movie.getMoviePoster();
        String title = movie.getTitle();
        String releaseDate = movie.getDate();
        String voteAverage = movie.getVoteAverage();
        String plot = movie.getPlot();

        ImageView poster = findViewById(R.id.details_image);
        Picasso.with(this).load(image).into(poster);

        TextView name = findViewById(R.id.details_title);
        name.setText((getResources().getString(R.string.movie_title)) + " " + title);

        TextView dateRelease = findViewById(R.id.details_release_date);
        dateRelease.setText((getResources().getString(R.string.release_date)) + " " + releaseDate);

        TextView averageVote = findViewById(R.id.details_voter_average);
        averageVote.setText((getResources().getString(R.string.vote_average)) + " " + voteAverage);

        TextView moviePlot = findViewById(R.id.details_plot);
        moviePlot.setText((getResources().getString(R.string.plot)) + " " + plot);

        ImageView watchTrailer = findViewById(R.id.imageView);

//        watchTrailer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
//            @Override
//            public void onClick(View v) {
//                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(trailerUrl.toString()));
//                Log.v("OnClick URL",trailerUrl.toString());
//                startActivity(intent);
//            }
//        });

    }

    public class FetchTrailer extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... strings) {
            final String YOUTUBE_ID = "id";
            final String RESULTS = "results";
            String youtubeId = " ";

            Intent intent = getIntent();
            Movie movie = intent.getParcelableExtra("movie");
            String id = movie.getID();

            final URL trailerUrl = NetworkUtils.buildUrlTrailer(id);
            Log.v("Built trailer url", trailerUrl.toString());

            try {
                String jsonResponse = NetworkUtils.getReponseFromHttpUrl(trailerUrl);

                JSONObject moviesObject = new JSONObject(jsonResponse);

                JSONArray resultsArray = moviesObject.getJSONArray(RESULTS);

                for(int i = 0; i < resultsArray.length(); i ++){
                    JSONObject movieObject = resultsArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    youtubeId = movieObject.getString(YOUTUBE_ID);
                    Log.v("youtubeid", youtubeId);
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }
    }

    //Tell the new method to get the data based on the search term within the url.
    private void loadMovieData() {
        //If there is a network connection, fetch the data.
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        boolean isConnected = activeNetwork != null &&
                activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();
        if (isConnected) {
            new FetchTrailer().execute();
        } else {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.no_internet_toast), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what are you using to retrive the YouTube video information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems youtubeId is a pre-requisite for your DetailsActivity. So we would need youtubeId prior to DetailsActivity initialization.

In your previous activity from where user can be landed to DetailsActivity , before calling *startActivity(intent)* call your

> loadMovieData()

method as is, you would have to declare method in prior activity. After that pass the youtubeId through intent to DetailsActivity, and you can retrieve value in oncreate():

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, 
NextActivity.class);
myIntent.putExtra("youtubeId", value); //Optional parameters
CurrentActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
```

Extras are retrieved on the other side via:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 Intent intent = getIntent();
 String value = intent.getStringExtra("youtubeId"); //if it's a string you 
 stored.
}
```

Comment: thank you I did what you suggested and that worked.  On a side note do you have any idea why this post got down voted twice? That has been happening to my questions lately and I am not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Callback Listener to achieve this

```
public interface FetchTrailerListener {
   public void onTrailerFetched(String youtubeId);
}
```

Make `DetailsActivity` to implement this. Pass this listener reference to asynctask when you are instantiating it.In this way from your postexecute notify the activity through this listener.

```
protected void onPostExecute( String youtubeId) {
   fetchTrailerListenr.onTrailerFetched(youtubeId);
}
```